# I want to create a vote system with jQuery but not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a function with jQuery but I can't. When you press a button then an arrow will move to 36 degrees. I have 5 buttons and the circle is 180 degrees.

My code is working in one way but it's not in reverse, which means when you press button 1 to 5 it's working but when I try to click randomly then it is not working.

[Here is what i am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujs1h.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ang36").click(function() {
    $("#silder_image").removeClass("animate1");
    $("#silder_image").addClass("animate1");
  });
  
  $("#ang72").click(function() {
    $("#silder_image").removeClass("animate2");
    $("#silder_image").addClass("animate2");
  });
  
  $("#ang108").click(function() {
    $("#silder_image").removeClass("animate3");
    $("#silder_image").addClass("animate3");
  });
  
  $("#ang144").click(function() {
    $("#silder_image").removeClass("animate4");
    $("#silder_image").addClass("animate4");
  });
  
  $("#ang180").click(function() {
    $("#silder_image").removeClass("animate5");
    $("#silder_image").addClass("animate5");
  });
});
```

```css
.slider_area {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.silder_image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.animate1 {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.animate1 img,
.animate2 img,
.animate3 img,
.animate4 img,
.animate5 img {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.animate2 {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.animate3 {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.animate4 {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.animate5 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition-duration: 5s;
}

.triggrs {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: -171px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_area">
  <div id="silder_image">
    <img src="Slider Vote.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="triggrs">
    <button id="ang36">button1</button>
    <button id="ang72">button2</button>
    <button id="ang108">button3</button>
    <button id="ang144">button4</button>
    <button id="ang180">button5</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to remove *all other classes*, not the one you're adding in the very next line.

Comment: @ChrisG how to remove multiple class at the same time

Comment: @ChrisG  You are great  It's working perfectly  --- thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can remove lots of duplicate code: https://jsfiddle.net/8bk0v165/

Comment: @ChrisG I'd suggest making that an answer. The question is more than high quality enough to deserve one, and it's a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another approach which could also help you further (maybe).

```js
let needle = document.querySelector('#needle ');
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')

btns.forEach( btn=>{ btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let level = this.dataset.deg;
  needle.style.transform = "rotate("+Number(level)+"deg)"});
})
```

```css
#panel {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  background: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e8e000 50%,#e50000 100%);
}

#needle {
  width: 6px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #4361ff;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform .75s cubic-bezier(.31,-0.52,.84,1.55);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div class="circle">
    <div id="needle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button data-deg="30">1</button>
  <button data-deg="60">2</button>
  <button data-deg="90">3</button>
  <button data-deg="120">4</button>
  <button data-deg="150">5</button>
</div>
```